# Как сделать чтобы форму можно было потащить за какую-нибудь произвольную область?

Tags: delphi

Как сделать чтобы форму можно было бы потащить за какую-нибудь произвольную область формы?

Comment: В простейшем случае - обрабатывать WM_NCHITTEST и возвращать HT_CAPTION

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Один из вариантов, наиболее мне симпатичный.

```
procedure TForm1.FormMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
    ReleaseCapture;
    SendMessage(Form1.Handle, WM_SYSCOMMAND, $F012, 0) ;
end;
```

Comment: Волшебное число совсем не симпатично :(

Comment: Увы `SC_DRAGMOVE` в Dephi нигде не определен.

Comment: Симпатичность тут в том, что на все про все ушло 2 строки и один обработчик.

Comment: > Увы SC_DRAGMOVE в Dephi нигде не определен.

Довольно слабое оправдание. Кстати, и метод с WM_NCHITTEST будет не менее лаконичен.

Comment: Никто вам не запрещает написать где-нибудь `const SC_DRAGMOVE = $F012;`

> Кстати, и метод с WM_NCHITTEST будет не менее лаконичен.
Согласен. Но у метода WM_NCHITTEST есть один минус: в форму больше не будут приходить мышиные события.

Answer (score 0):

В объявление формы добавь следующее:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  ...
  private
    { Private declarations }
    procedure WMNCHITTEST(var Msg: TWMNCHitTest);message WM_NCHITTEST;
```

а в самом коде пишите следующее:

```
procedure TForm1.WMNCHITTEST(var Msg: TWMNCHitTest);
begin
  Inherited;
  with Msg do
  if Result = htClient then
    Result := htCaption;
end;
```